# The disadvantages of high IQ

Tags: iq

Some disadvantages about being intelligent are supposedly: 1. You make conclusions too fast 2. If you insist on logic, you must work as an engineer because nobody else cares about logic. 3. You have difficulties to forget things that you might be better off forgetting.

Are there any more disadvantages known?

Comment: At the moment, the question is not answerable, I'm afraid, because it is unclear what kind of "disadvantages" you are looking for. As exaggerated examples: IQ predicts academic success and access to higher education, as a disadvantage, you will have to put up with all those heavy books you'll end up bying. It's also a burden to come up with uses for so much time, as IQ predicts longevity. In a similar way, the examples you list as your premise seem opinion-based. Why is making conclusions quickly a bad thing?

Comment: Neither of your claims are I think *known*. They seem like, at best, mere speculation, and at worst, proved wrong.